# querySelector needs time out in ionic page / angular

Tags: angular, dom, ionic2

This works:

```
 ionViewDidLoad() {  

  var that = this;

          setTimeout(function () {
              that.img = that.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.user-image');
              alert(that.img.src);
          }, 300);
}
```

This doesn't

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

      var that = this;
      that.img = that.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.user-image');
      alert(that.img.src);

}
```

I am sure this is not correct behavior. And I really don't want to have to set a time out to get this. So why is this the case and how can it be fixed?

Int the html file I have:

```
<img class="user-image img-responsive full-width " *ngIf="user.pictureURL" src="myurl.com{{user.pictureURL}}"  />
```

Comment: Could you please add some more code related to how that image is being created? Is it the result of an http call?

Comment: ok edited the the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the html template may get loaded after the call.
You need to use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child) to get the [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html)

```
<img #imageId class="user-image img-responsive full-width " *ngIf="user.pictureURL" src="myurl.com{{user.pictureURL}}"  /><!--set id with # -->
```

In component:

```
import {ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

//...In class,
@ViewChild('imageId') imageElement:ElementRef;

ionViewDidLoad() {
   alert(this.imageElement.nativeElement.src);

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as is do I need to add a directive as well?

Comment: you need to import `ElementRef` as well

Comment: It is imported - nothing gets alerted.

Comment: are you able to log it? you have an ngIf.. does it come through an http call?

Comment: If so you should set it within the subscribe or then.. depending on where you are fetching it..

Comment: Again this works with the time out but not otherwise.

Comment: "user.pictureURL" how are you getting this?

Comment: In the constructor of this class I have a subscribe. However it will do it with static urls too. So I think this is irrelevant and related to some DOM delay.

Comment: ngIf manipulates the DOM directly.. It wont load the image element till the condition is valid..try calling the alert in the subscribe

Comment: I already know what the link is in the subscribe. I am trying to get it from the dom.